# Quiz tutorial, display the button "submit" only when one of the answers is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a quiz following a tutorial on YouTube.
I see that even if you don't select any of the option you can still proceed with the next question, so for avoid this I would like to display the button only when one of the radio button is selected. Could anyone help me to add the if statement for this.

```js
var quiz;
var quizStatus;
var pos = 0;
var correct = 0;
var chA, chB, chC, choice;
var question;
var choices;
var buttonC;
var questions = [
  ["Who is the king of the world?", "Jakub", "Tomek", "Darek", "A"],
  ["What is the capital of Poland?", "Warsaw", "Paris", "Rome", "A"],
  ["Who is Robert Lewandowski?", "An Actor", "A football player", "A Doctor", "B"]
];

function displayQuestions() {
  if (pos === questions.length) {
    quiz.innerHTML = "you compleate the test <br>";
    quiz.innerHTML += "your score is " + correct;
    quiz.innerHTML += '<input type="button"  value="Restart" onclick="restartTest()">'

  }

  quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
  quizStatus = document.getElementById("quiz-status");
  question = questions[pos][0];
  chA = questions[pos][1];
  chB = questions[pos][2];
  chC = questions[pos][3];
  quizStatus.innerHTML = "Question" + (pos + 1) + "of" + questions.length;
  "<br>";
  quiz.innerHTML = question + "<br>";
  quiz.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="choices" value="A">' + chA + "<br>"
  quiz.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="choices" value="B">' + chB + "<br>"
  quiz.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="choices" value="C">' + chC + "<br>"
  quiz.innerHTML += '<input id="buttonC" type="button"  value="Submit" onclick="submitQuestion()">'
}

function submitQuestion() {
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  buttonC = document.getElementById("buttonC");

  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (choice == questions[pos][4]) {
    correct++;
  }
  pos++;
  displayQuestions();

}


function restartTest() {
  pos = 0
  correct = 0
  displayQuestions()
}

window.addEventListener("load", displayQuestions, false);
```

```html
<div id="quiz-status"></div>
<div id="quiz"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: if (choices[i].checked === false) {
buttonC.style.visibility ="hidden";
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is a link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/superawesomecoder1/pen/BVJjXY

Basically what I did was I added the disabled tag to the button, making it disabled until the user checks one of the checkboxes.

```
quiz.innerHTML += '<input id="buttonC" type="button"  value="Submit" onclick="submitQuestion()" disabled>'
```

Then, just add the following to each of the buttons.  In my example I made a shortened varible so the code is a little bit shorter.

```
onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;buttonC&quot;).disabled = false">
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks!, sorry for bother you again, but I can't understand this part of the code:(&quot;buttonC&quot;).disabled = false"> would you be kind and explain it to me or a link to a tutorial is more than fine :)

Comment: Yes, because there are multiple quotes inside one another, the "&quot;" basically translates to a quote mark.  So it translates to ("buttonC").disabled = false>  This enables the submit button so that the user can submit their choice.  Here is a link to an explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled